# Use a generic method to find the max value of a 2D array of strings

Tags: java, generics, multidimensional-array, max

So, we're going over generics in my CS class right now. For our homework, we are supposed to write four methods, one that finds the max value of a 2D array. The method we were given is:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(E[][] list)
```

And here's the code for the method:

```
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(E[][] list) {
    E max = list[0][0];
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < list[i].length; j++) {
            if (max.compareTo(list[i][j]) < 0) {
                max = list[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to test it. Honestly, I'm probably overthinking it. I created a 2D array and filled it with values, like so:

```
String[][] list1 = {{"red", "green"}, {"yellow", "blue"}};
```

But I don't know how to implement the method. I tried using for-loops to cycle through the array, but then I didn't know what to do after that. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `System.out.println(max(list1));` ? You should probably initialize `i` and `j` to `0` as well.

Comment: Max method is wrong, it will miss max values on list[0][1] and list[1][0]

Comment: How are you supposed to write four methods? To do what?

Comment: @Klaimmore My professor told us to combine four problems out of our textbook into one program for our homework and to test them. The methods find 1.the max value of a 2d array 2.perform a binary search 3.sort and 4.shuffle arrays. Then we create 2 arrays/ArrayLists for each method to test them, one of ints and one of strings.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Will do. Thank you!